# UITableView clear background

Tags: ios, uitableview

I realize that iOS 7 has not officially been released and we should not discuss it BUT I am going crazy trying to figure out this problem. On iOS 6, my table view was transparent and looked great. First time running iOS 7, and the background is white.

I have tried making the table backgroundColor, cell color etc etc to UIColor clearColor but have no change.

How to fix this problem?

[image: the table]

Comment: Tried setting the table's `backgroundView` to a clear one?

Comment: Could you show the code where you are setting the background colour? What about the parent view? Perhaps the table view background is clear but the parent isn't?

Comment: I noticed this same thing but when I installed the same app that predated my current version to iOS 7.0 it wasn't happening. Does this problem lie in xCode5.0 then?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
    // Fix for iOS 7 to clear backgroundColor
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIView new] autorelease];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView new] autorelease];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Also, make sure that your tableview actually has transparent background (in storyboard):
[image]

Comment: George, add that code inside the method - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: For the cases, if you really need selectedBackgroundView, you can put the following in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

 cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBgImage.png"]] autorelease];

or even in awakeFromNib: self.selectedBackgroundView = ...

Note, that:  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; does not work in awakeFromNib under iOS7.

But:  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; works properly only in cellForRowAtIndexPath for iOS 7.0

Comment: Only need to add the row: cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: This works like charm cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: How to do this in Swift?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iOS 12. I just spent a good hour trying to figure out what happened only to find my code working fine on iOS 11. No idea what the problem is. View debugging leads me nowhere except to the backgroundColor property of the TableView not reacting to my changes.

Comment: In Swift... tableView.backgroundColor = nil.   In the cellForRowAt method, dequeue your cell and set cell.backgroundColor = nil before returning it.  I just confirmed this is working in iOS 13.

Answer (score 58):

**Put this:**

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

**In this section:**

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: In iOS 6, it is sufficient to set the `backgroundView` to an empty view, but this additional code is needed for iOS 7.

Answer (score 25):

Try setting backgroundView to nil first.

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Not sure if this is a change in documentation with iOS7 or has always been there and just did not affect background color, but per [UITableView Class Reference @property backgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView)

*"You must set this property to nil to set the background color of the table view."*

**edit: corrected code syntax**

Answer (score 25):

This has been answered, but incorrectly in a lot of ways.

You need to implement the below delegate method:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

You can't put the fix in cellForRowAtIndexPath because that is after the cell is rendered, and it will flash a white background before the background gets set to clear (on slower devices).

Use this delegate method and your problems are solved!

Comment: Yes. For iOS 7 this is the way to clear the background. All the other suggestions above might not work.

Answer (score 15):

Actually the officially correct place to change cell background color is different according to documentation ([UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

> Whether you use a predefined or custom cell, you can change the cell’s
>   background using the    backgroundView property or by changing the
>   inherited backgroundColor property. In iOS 7, cells have a white
>   background by default; in earlier versions of iOS, cells inherit the
>   background color of the enclosing table view. If you want to change
>   the background color of a cell, do so in the
>   tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view
>   delegate.

Comment: I am trying this, but the very first cells shown all have a white background. If I create new cells by scrolling, then they will have the transparent background I want. Not sure what else to try…

Comment: Never mind, it appears to be a timing issue. I was doing stuff in awakeFromNib, which was too early.

Answer (score 9):

swift 3, 4 and 5

```swift
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 6):

This is quite a frustrating problem. Here's my current solution:

Add this to your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Oh god. Thank you. Saved my night. Your answer should have been the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in iOS7+:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;`
```

and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

This did only work for me when i edited a clear background color for each cell and a clear color for the table itself.. BOTH PROGRAMMATICALLY

to set the clear color for the table:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    initMenu()
    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

to set the color for the cells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tablecellid", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this code snippet

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Answer (score 4):

First set

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Second set

```
tableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing to nice. The default color of UITable seems to be white (I don't know why)

[image: Background white]

But better change that.

Comment: Perfect! That was the missing peace. No additional line of code needed!

Answer (score 3):

create IB Outlet for table view
 @IBOutlet weak var yourTable : UITableView!

in view load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    yourTable.delegate = self
    yourTable.dataSource = self

    yourTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

if you want to clear color of Cell also do this in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my app, I had to set the `backgroundColor` on my `UITableViewCell` class to `[UIColor clearColor]` color when I updated for `iOS 7`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the cell was created using a xib. it seems like interface builder on xcode5 has trouble setting clearColor to the cell.backgroundColor.

All I needed to do was indeed to set

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// get the cell from the nib
//then force the backgroundColor
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
return cell;
}
```

Comment: control reaches end of non-void function

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[myTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
[myTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

And

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select Clear Color on View Background for the table and for the cell also.

Answer (score 2):

**swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Fix iOS 7 clear backgroundColor compatibility 
// I Think this two lines only are enough

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView new] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.backgroundView = UIView()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Working for me......

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

in viewDidLoad.

if this is not working, try:

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```