# iOS - UITableView Cell goes Blank when built on iOS7 but works on earlier Versions

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, ios7.1

**What is happening?**

I am updating an application that was developed on iOS 4.3 and now while building its update on iOS7 the TableView Goes totally White.

**What i have Tried?**

I already have checked the following questions **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132042/uitableview-with-custom-cells-draws-fine-on-ios-6-but-completely-white-in-ios-7)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961397/uitableview-cell-background-difference-in-ios7-0)**

**What is my application Flow?**

Basically,There is a UItableView and in each cell of a tableView there is ViewController's View Added in that View and in each View there is a Paging Control and in that Paging control there are custom View just like a grid which was not available in iOS that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure to add the subviews to the cells contentView rather then adding them directly to the cell?

Another thing that changed in iOS 7 with UITableViewCells was the addition of `UITableViewCellScrollView` to the underlying structure.

here is a visual example of the change: http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check and let you know