# How to make a transparent tableview?

Tags: ios, background, tableview, transparent

im trying to make a menu like FIFA app but i can't put the tableview in a transparent color,so the background image can be visible, can anyone help me?? I've tried of everything, any of this answers worked for me: [UITableView clear background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753411/uitableview-clear-background) so i really need your help.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to setting the background color of the table view to clear, you have to set the background color of the table view *cells*.  And that, at least in my experience, has been somewhat tricky and couldn't be easily done via Interface Builder (the storyboard or the xib).

So you have to set the background color on your cells directly. For example, during your [`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a) delegate method, you'd do something like:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And as rmaddy points out, Apple documentation for that method states:

> This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based
>   properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and
>   background color.

Comment: Actually the cell background needs to be set in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: My experience has been that is really only works in the `willDisplayCell...` delegate. The docs for `willDisplayCell...` also state to use it to set the background color.

Comment: yeah, I see it in the documentation, and I've updated my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work yet, heres how the tableview looks like, maybe helps, its in a container view: freeimagehosting net/scgnp

Comment: Did you set the *delegate* of the table view? It's a separate thing from the table view data source.