# background for uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
MyTableCell *cell=[[MyTableCell alloc]init];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The above lines of code are still showing the white color of the cell's background and hiding the background image of the tableview.

Comment: You also have to change background color of `TableView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView clear background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753411/uitableview-clear-background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to you storyboard and set the color of your uitableview cell to clear color from there.And also set uitabelview color also to clear color.

Or in you viewdidload  set tableview background color to clear color and in cellforrow at indexparth delagate set

```
cell.contentView.backGroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor]
```

Comment: please tell how can I add gap between two cells in the tableview?

Comment: If You want to do it programatically , then simply add following code in you cell for row at indexpath delegate :

   UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 3)];/// change size as you need.
            separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];// you can also put image here
            [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

Comment: will try it and get back to u

Comment: I don't want to insert a separator line I just want gap in between them

Comment: Go to you Storyboard , then in you tableview cell add a view inside it leaving gaps from top and bottom . Use the gap according to your need. Then add all the controllers like label , button etc  in the view. Set border of the view if you want . you will achieve hat you want.

Answer (score 0):

set the contentview background color also

```
cell.contentView.backGroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor];
cell.backGroundView.backGroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor];
cell.selectedBackGroundView.backGroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor];
```

Also check if you cleared the `tableView.backGroundColor` also

Comment: Nothing happened on doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I am so sorry but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell(UITableViewCell *)cellforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one. I have solved the problem. I changed the background attribute in the attribute inspector in the storyboard for my cell object from default to clear color and it worked.

Comment: i think you should accept my answer as it was my Solution to change it the background color from storyboard.

Comment: I don't know how to.